# Prove using weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Can someone help me out?

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n\sim N(0,1)$ with 
>   $$
>   \mathbb{C}\textrm{ov}(X_{i},X_{j})=\begin{cases}
>   \begin{array}{ccc}
> \rho & \textrm{if} & \left|i-j\right|=1\\
> 0 & \textrm{if} & \left|i-j\right|>1
> \end{array}\end{cases}
> $$
>
> Prove that $\dfrac{S_{n}}{n}\xrightarrow{\text{P}}0$.

Comment: I have solved. It´s easy.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.

We have to prove:
$\dfrac{S_{n}}{n}\overset{\mathrm{P}}{\longrightarrow}0\;\Leftrightarrow\;\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\dfrac{S_{n}}{n}-0\right|>\epsilon\right)\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$.

Since $\mathbb{E}\left(\dfrac{S_{n}}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\mathbb{E}\left(S_{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(X_{i}\right)=0$ and using Chevichev's inequality we have:

$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\dfrac{S_{n}}{n}-0\right|>\epsilon\right)\leq\dfrac{\mathbb{V}\textrm{ar}\left(\dfrac{S_{n}}{n}\right)}{\epsilon^{2}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\cdot\mathbb{V}\textrm{ar}\left(S_{n}\right)}{\epsilon^{2}}=\dfrac{\mathbb{V}\textrm{ar}\left(S_{n}\right)}{n^{2}\epsilon^{2}}=\dfrac{\mathbb{V}\textrm{ar}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)}{n^{2}\epsilon^{2}}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{V}\textrm{ar}\left(X_{i}\right)+2\sum_{i<j}\mathbb{C}\textrm{ov}\left(X_{i},X_{j}\right)}{n^{2}\epsilon^{2}}=\dfrac{n+2(n-1)\rho}{n^{2}\epsilon^{2}}\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$